# need coding structure for starting pages of my thesis

Tags: header-footer, titles

I need to write starting pages of my university format in my thesis, inlcuding title of thesis, supervisor's signature, headers and footers etc, and structural images are attached. kindly give me the coding structure for these pages thanks [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: Although my advice is not  use any template but start from scratch, there are many templates of thesis out there that can show you how to do  a thesis structure. Try to do something similar and then ask  for specific problems you faced (e.g., how to make the rule for the signatures, or how to have roman number of pages, etc.).